# Dual recursion across kd-trees to find the closest approach between two sets of points

Tags: python, geometry, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, computational-geometry

I have constructed kd-trees for two sets of points, in order to find the closest bichromatic pairing between the two sets:

[image]

The kd-trees are stored as python dictionaries, which can be found in the code below, and are passed to a function ('`closest`') that is meant to simultaneously recursively analyse both trees to find the closest approach between the sets. This is to prevent having to brute force the problem.

My first attempt is based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58448670/finding-the-distance-between-two-polygons-in-numpy). With this attempt, I can't find a condition that forces the function to 'bounce back' when it hits a leaf i.e the `if` statement designed to return the minimum distances between the leaves and the existing minimum is never reached.

First attempt - full code provided for context, this question only pertains to the function 'closest':

```
from operator import itemgetter
import math
import time
import pprint
import numpy as np


# builds the trees
def build_kd_tree(ar, depth=0, k=2):
    if len(ar) <= 0:
        return None
    axis = depth % k
    sorted_ar = sorted(ar, key=itemgetter(axis))
    idx = int(math.floor(len(ar)/2))
    return {
       'point': sorted_ar[idx],
       'left': build_kd_tree(sorted_ar[:idx], depth + 1),
       'right': build_kd_tree(sorted_ar[idx+1:], depth + 1)
    }


def min_dist(p1, p2):
    d1 = math.hypot(p1[0] - p2[0], p1[1] - p2[1])
    return d1


# function designed to simultaneously recurse two trees to find the closest approach
def closest(k1,k2,lim=float("inf")):

    cc1 = [k1[value] for value in k1 if k1[value] is not None and type(k1[value]) == dict]
    cc2 = [k2[value] for value in k2 if k2[value] is not None and type(k2[value]) == dict]

    if len(cc1) == 0 and len(cc2) == 0:
        return min(lim, min_dist(k1['point'], k2['point']))

    for md, c1, c2 in sorted((min_dist(c1['point'], c2['point']), c1, c2) for c1 in cc1 for c2 in cc2):
        if md >= lim: break
        lim = min(lim, closest(c1, c2, lim))
    return lim

# some example coordinates
px_coords=np.array([299398.56,299402.16,299410.25,299419.7,299434.97,299443.75,299454.1,299465.3,299477.,299488.25,299496.8,299499.5,299501.28,299504.,299511.62,299520.62,299527.8,299530.06,299530.06,299525.12,299520.2,299513.88,299508.5,299500.84,299487.34,299474.78,299458.6,299444.66,299429.8,299415.4,299404.84,299399.47,299398.56,299398.56])
py_coords=np.array([822975.2,822989.56,823001.25,823005.3,823006.7,823005.06,823001.06,822993.4,822977.2,822961.,822943.94,822933.6,822925.06,822919.7,822916.94,822912.94,822906.6,822897.6,822886.8,822869.75,822860.75,822855.8,822855.4,822857.2,822863.44,822866.6,822870.6,822876.94,822886.8,822903.,822920.3,822937.44,822954.94,822975.2])
qx_coords=np.array([384072.1,384073.2,384078.9,384085.7,384092.47,384095.3,384097.12,384097.12,384093.9,384088.9,384082.47,384078.9,384076.03,384074.97,384073.53,384072.1])
qy_coords=np.array([780996.8,781001.1,781003.6,781003.6,780998.25,780993.25,780987.9,780981.8,780977.5,780974.7,780974.7,780977.2,780982.2,780988.25,780992.5,780996.8])

# some more example coordinates
#px_coords = np.array([299398,299402,299410.25,299419.7,299398])
#py_coords = np.array([822975.2,822920.3,822937.44,822954.94,822975.2])
#qx_coords = np.array([292316,292331.22,292329.72,292324.72,292319.44,292317.2,292316])
#qy_coords = np.array([663781,663788.25,663794,663798.06,663800.06,663799.3,663781])

# this is all just formatting the coordinates - only important thing to know is that p_midpoints and q_midpoints are two distinct sets of points, and are the targets in this question
px_edges = np.stack((px_coords, np.roll(px_coords, -1)),1)
px_midpoints = np.array(abs(px_coords + np.roll(px_coords, -1))/2)
py_edges = np.stack((py_coords, np.roll(py_coords, -1)),1)
py_midpoints = np.array(abs(py_coords + np.roll(py_coords, -1))/2)

p_edges = np.stack((px_edges, py_edges), axis=-1)[:-1]
p_midpoints = np.stack((px_midpoints, py_midpoints), axis=-1)[:-1]

qx_edges = np.stack((qx_coords, np.roll(qx_coords, -1)),1)
qx_midpoints = np.array(abs(qx_coords + np.roll(qx_coords, -1))/2)
qy_edges = np.stack((qy_coords, np.roll(qy_coords, -1)),1)
qy_midpoints = np.array(abs(qy_coords + np.roll(qy_coords, -1))/2)

q_edges = np.stack((qx_edges, qy_edges), axis=-1)[:-1]
q_midpoints = np.stack((qx_midpoints, qy_midpoints), axis=-1)[:-1]

# where the tree is actually built
p_tree = build_kd_tree(p_midpoints)
q_tree = build_kd_tree(q_midpoints)

# uncommect to see structure of tree
#pprint.pprint(p_tree)

near_distance = closest(p_tree, q_tree)

# brute force for testing
#distances = []
#for p_point in p_midpoints:
#    for q_point in q_midpoints:
#        distances.append(min_dist(p_point, q_point))
#
#m_dist = sorted(distances)[0]
#print(m_dist)
```

In my second attempt I tried to force the function to stop recursing when it hit the leaf of the tree. This works for the smaller of the two sample coordinate sets, but does not work for the larger of the two sample coordinate sets, failing with the same problem.

Second attempt - only 'closest' function, can be swapped out like-for-like with namesake in above code:

```
def closest(k1,k2,lim=float("inf")):
    cc1 = [k1]
    cc1 = cc1 + [k1[value] for value in k1 if k1[value] is not None and type(k1[value]) == dict]
    cc2 = [k2]
    cc2 = cc2 + [k2[value] for value in k2 if k2[value] is not None and type(k2[value]) == dict]

    if len(cc1) == 1 and len(cc2) == 1:
        return min(lim, min_dist(k1['point'], k2['point']))

    md = [[min_dist(cc1[i]['point'], cc2[j]['point']), i, j, (cc1[i]['point'], cc2[j]['point'])] for i in range(len(cc1) >> 1, len(cc1)) for j in range(len(cc1) >> 1, len(cc2))]
    md = sorted(md, key=itemgetter(0))
    for h in range(0, len(md)):
        lim = min(lim, closest(cc1[md[h][1]], cc2[md[h][2]],lim))
    return lim
```

I'm aware that out-of-the-box solutions exist to solve this problem, but this is an area that I would like to understand better by building my own from scratch. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The `min_dist` (which shouldn’t be used for individual (point) objects) must apply to **bounding volumes**—in this case, the only such available are the half-spaces defined by the various splitting (hyper)planes.  Note that the dual recursion is not very efficient in that case because so many of the (minimum) distances are 0; it might be possible to augment the algorithm by *constructing* a bounding box as the intersection of the various half-spaces associated with the *path* to a node, but there could easily be a much better algorithm (for points!).

Answer (score 0):

The working principle of a kD-tree is that you can quickly find bounds on the shortest and longest distance of the query point (say it is red) to a subset of the points contained in a known rectangle (say arranged in a blue tree). In addition, the rectangles are obtained by successive divisions, which makes the estimates even simpler to compute.

If you want to adapt to the bichromatic case, you can process the rectangles generated by the red tree instead of a single red point and adapt the rule to estimate the shortest (0 in case of overlaps) and longest distances to the blue rectangles.

There are different ways to organize the subdivisions of both trees, such as

- for every subdivision level of the red tree, subdivide the blue tree down to the leaves,
- conversely for every subdivision level of the blue tree, subdivide the red tree down to the leaves,
- or on every subdivision level, subdivide both red and blue and consider all combinations.

I have no idea how to choose among these options (other than by fully trying them).